# How can I create volume and number in the custom .bst file?

Tags: bibtex

I started modifying my osajnl.bst file. (http://www.opticsinfobase.org/submit/templates/wordwp/osajnl.bst)

I want to modify the .bst file.

There is a big problem as following.

I need to get the citation style like **1**(2).

In this OSA bst file, I can get volume **1**, but I do not have volume+number **1**(2)!!

How can I change the original OSA file to get the proper citation style?

Answer (score 2):

Just change the following function

```
"FUNCTION {format.vol.num.pages}

{ volume field.or.null

 duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$

{

"volume" bibinfo.check

}

if$

  bolden

  eid empty$


    { format.journal.pages }

    { format.journal.eid }

  if$

}"

by 

FUNCTION {format.vol.num.pages}

{ volume field.or.null

  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$

    {

      "volume" bibinfo.check

    }

  if$

  bolden

  number "number" bibinfo.check duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$

    {

      swap$ duplicate$ empty$

        { "there's a number but no volume in " cite$ * warning$ }

        'skip$

      if$

      swap$

      "(" swap$ * ")" *

    }

  if$ *

    eid empty$

    { format.journal.pages }

    { format.journal.eid }

  if$

}
```